# How to gradually encrypt the tshark output file along the capture?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption, wireshark, tshark

In order to secure a packet capture, which method would you use to make all (or close to all) past captured packet utterly unaccessible unless a given password is given.

My habbits are

- to mount an `ecrypt` partition

  ```
  mount -t ecryptfs /srv /srv
  ```
- to run `tshark` with a buffer and save files on the encrypted filesystem `/media/`

  ```
  tshark -B 100k -i wlan0 -w /srv/capture-file.pcap
  ```

The problem with this method is that the file `capture-file.pcap` is only unaccessible once the `ecryptfs` system is unmounted.

**How can I do a capture with no non-encrypted version of the capture on the system at all?**

Answer (score 1):

The de facto standard tool for encrypting data is [GnuPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) (or the compatible proprietary program [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).

Generate a key pair on the machine where you'll want to decrypt the data (`gpg --gen-key`). Export the public key (`gpg --export …`) and copy it to the machine where you'll be encrypting (of course you can skip this step if the encryption and the decryption will be done on the same machine). Then run

```
tshark … -w - | gpg -e >capture.pcap.gpg
```

To decrypt, just run `gpg capture.pcap.gpg`.

GnuPG can also do password-based encryption, with `-c` instead of `-e`. This is less secure for two reasons:

- Because people tend to choose insufficiently strong passwords, and even the best memorable password isn't as strong as a randomly-generated key.
- Because the information necessary to encrypt is also sufficient to decrypt, whereas using an asymmetric key pair makes it possible to encrypt without having the credentials to decrypt.

Answer (score -1):

For encrypted capture

```
tshark -w - | openssl enc -des3 -out capture.pcap.des3
```

Reading with

```
openssl enc -d -des3 -out capture.pcap.des3 | wireshark -i - k
```

Comment: No. Don't do that. `openssl enc` is very bad: it doesn't use a proper password derivation function. See e.g. [Cryptosense](https://cryptosense.com/weak-key-derivation-in-openssl/), [how to securely hash passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) (deriving a key from a password is mostly the same as hasing a password).